# linq-to-sql: GROUP BY and MIN() in SELECT part

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, linq-to-sql

In MySql I have the following (simplified) query:

```
SELECT 
  ct.ColumnA, 
  MIN(IF(Constant + mt.ColA >= mt.ColB, Constant + mt.ColA, mt.ColB)) AS ResultCol
FROM 
  master_table mt
    INNER JOIN child_table ct ON (ct.MasterID = mt.ID)
WHERE
  ct.ColumnB = 1
  ...
GROUP BY
  ct.ColumnA;
```

This query works perfectly in MySql, but I can't translate it into Linq2sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how I've done it (didn't test it with linq2sql exactly, I use linq2db project):

```
var q = 
  from mt in db.MasterTable
  join ct in db.ChildTable on mt.ID equals ct.MasterID
  where
    ct.ColumnB = 1 &&
    ...
  group new { ct, mt } by new { ct.ColumnA } into g
  select
    new
    {
      g.Key.ColumnA,
      ResultCol = g.Min(x => myConstant + x.mt.ColA > x.mt.ColB
                                ? myConstant + x.mt.ColA
                                : x.mt.ColB)
    };
```